# Unusual behavior when using ternary operator to append to string

Tags: python

In python, when I append an empty string to a non empty string, the results are as expected

```
>>> "1234" + ""
>>> "1234"
```

But when I use a ternary operator like so, this is the output

```
>>> "1234" + "abcd" if True else ""
>>> "1234abcd"

>>> "1234" + "abcd" if False else ""
>>> ""
```

Why do I get an empty string in the second case instead of `"1234"` ?

Comment: Compare your statement with `"1234" + ("abcd" if False else "")`. And perhaps with  `("1234" + "abcd") if False else ""` as well.

Comment: You should look into operator precedence `+` trumps the ternary operator.

Comment: That's because `if False` is always going to lead to the else condition, no matter what is on the left.

Comment: Precedence precedence [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). "Conditional expressions (sometimes called a “ternary operator”) have the lowest priority of all Python operations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to expand @BrenBarn's answer (which is correct): if You want to get desired behavior, You should do it like this:

```
"1234" + ("abcd" if False else "")
```

or,

```
"1234" + "abcd" if False else "1234" + ""
```

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator binds more tightly than the ternary operator, so your code is interpreted as `("1234" + "abcd") if condition else ""`.  It returns the first string (the sum of two others) if the condition is True, otherwise it returns the empty string.